# Service worker register then - Undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typeerror, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I use default React code for registering service worker. I have reports in bugsnag that some users are getting `TypeError: undefined is not a function` on the line `.then(registration => {` inside registerValidSW.

For me it is working but for some probably not. I did not find where could be a problem.

Could you help me with this?

```
export function register() {
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' && 'serviceWorker' in navigator) {
const publicUrl = new URL(process.env.PUBLIC_URL, window.location.href);
if (publicUrl.origin !== window.location.origin) {
  return;
}

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  const swUrl = `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/service-worker.js`;

  if (isLocalhost) {
    .......
  } else {
    registerValidSW(swUrl);
  }
});
}
}

function registerValidSW(swUrl) {
 navigator.serviceWorker
.register(swUrl)
.then(registration => {
  registration.onupdatefound = () => {
    const installingWorker = registration.installing;
    if (installingWorker == null) {
      return;
    }
    installingWorker.onstatechange = () => {
      ...
    };
  };
})
.catch(error => {
  console.error('Error during service worker registration:', error);
});
}
```

Comment: I'm also facing this issue. Have you found anything about it? Thanks.

Comment: I'm encountering similar issue. This error is recorded on Chrome while on Firefox it's recorded as 'the operation is insecure'

Answer (score 2):

Serviceworker and its methods including `register` [are supported on all latest browsers excluding IE](https://caniuse.com/#search=service%20worker%20register).

It has been noticed that even when `serviceWorker` is accessible in `navigator`, property `register` is not present which should always return a promise.
[Chromium bug for the same.](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1062193)

For now, you could avoid this issue by adding the following check:

```
'serviceWorker' in navigator && 'register' in navigator.serviceWorker
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are using normal react app template which does not have service worker functions like `register()`

to use pwa react app create your react app by

```
npx create-react-app my-app --template cra-template-pwa
```

TypeScript equivalent

```
npx create-react-app my-app --template cra-template-pwa-typescript
```